# Unity - Root motion even when off, still moves the feet on my character out of place, then back to default place

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

So, I have a humanoid character that I animated in a pose where one of its legs is still (rotates but doesnt translate) and the other moves (translates and rotates). The character is meant to stay in place and does so in my modeling app, but in my unity game, even when root motion is checked off, the foot that is supposed to stay still, still moves back during the animation clip and than back into the default position at the end of the clip.

Example 2:
Also, in another animation clip, both feet are supposed to be on the ground, whilst the upper body does its thing. But both feet lift up during the animation. Its as if unity is trying to average out the distance between various limbs.

NOTE though that in both examples, the feet do have keyframes cos they may not translate but they do get affected via animation of other limbs as before baking the animation, the IK was on all rigs.

Why is this and how can I fix this pls? I cant post a sceenshot of the character as its under development and the concept needs protection, hence tried to explain it with two examples.

EDIT - Even in the little preview window at the bottom corner, the animation has the feet grounded, but in the game, the feet dont stay grounded. :(

Version = unity 4.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case, someone else runs into this, I found the answer. Turn on "Bake Into Pose" for each animation clip that is giving you this issue. More info here - http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RootMotion.html

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible to convert any animation to in-place.

please follow this recipe of doing animation to in-place.

1) click on model fbx.

2) click on your required animation that you want to in-place and open animation tab not animator.

you will see that animation is read only.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53kDA.png)

3) Duplicate this animation clip and click on it. Now you will see this animation clips is (read/write) and removes read only.

4) in animation properties tab scroll down and find "Animator.Root T"

5) click on open drop down and click on Root T.z and remove this "z" property as shown in screenshot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gg5VZ.png)

*if still not you get inplace try removing "x" property.